# Html Dom parser get first element

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

Hi i'm using `simple_html_dom` php library to get contents from other website.

I have below html structure,

```
<h1 class="nik_product_title" style="color: #000;">
  DSLR D7100
  <span class="new_big_parent">
    <span class="new_big_child">
      <span class="new_big_child1">new</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Using this

```
@$html->find ( 'div[class=nik_block_product_main_info_component_inner] h1',0)->plaintext;
```

But i'm getting output as `DSLR+D7100new`

How to get only first plain text i.e, need to fetch only `DSLR D7100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually get at that one with:

```
$html->find('h1 text', 0);
```

Comment: So simple !! Didn't aware of this. Thank you pguardiario.

Comment: @pguardiario Do you have any idea for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669373/php-simple-html-dom-parser-cant-get-content-on-pagination)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a core function to get the result what you want.

```
$html = str_get_html('<h1 class="nik_product_title" style="color: #000;">
DSLR D7100
<span class="new_big_parent">
<span class="new_big_child">
  <span class="new_big_child1">new</span>
</span>
</span>
</h1>');

$last_one =$html->find('h1.nik_product_title',0)->children (0)->plaintext;

$whole =$html->find('h1.nik_product_title',0)->plaintext;

$result = str_replace($last_one,"",$whole);
echo $result;
```