# Get content inside div but skip <span> inside that div simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom, plaintext

So i have a code which is inside a div class and inside that div class there is a text and one span with another text so i need to get content but not what is inside span and span.

Basically this is the code

```
<div class="somecontent">
    23:45
    <span>Tags:
      <a href="link to somewhere"> tag1</a>
      <a href="link to somewhere"> tag1</a>
      <a href="link to somewhere"> tag1</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

So i don't need what's inside span and those links. I just need to have this

```
23:45
```

Basically i just need to get the time of the video.

And im grabbing pages with simple_html_dom so what is my solution if anyone knows?

Comment: Check out the following question which @pguarianrio answers which solved the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631484/html-dom-parser-get-first-element/22632599#22632599

Comment: If you provide the url where you are scraping the data, we may find where the exact problem exists?

Comment: I did something similar as in url you posted. Im not sure if i should post url since, it's an adult site.

Comment: Then it is not advisable to give.

Answer (score 2):

Your're looking for:

```
$html->find('.somecontent text', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$doc = str_get_html($html);

foreach ($doc->find('div.somecontent') as $parent) {
    foreach ($parent->find('text') as $node) {
        if ($node->parent() === $parent) {
            echo trim($node->plaintext);
        }
    }
}
```

This becomes easier if you're using PHP's built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class. You can simply use an XPath expression to retrieve the text you need:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//div/text()') as $node) {
    echo trim($node->textContent);
}
```

The XPath expression `//div/text()` finds all text nodes that are inside a `<div>`.

Comment: If you sometimes wish you could use xpath with simple html dom you might like [this project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) - it lets you do: `$doc->find('//div/text()')` - I personally prefer css though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as a solution.

First i get all the text inside span, than i use str_replace to get all the text inside somecontent class and replace the one inside span with empty.

```
                $get_duration = $video->find('div[class="somecontent"]', 0)->children(0);
                $video_duration = str_replace($get_duration, '', $video->find('div[class="somecontent"]', 0)->innertext);
```